# How to embed CDATA using RABL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

When I try to create a node like:

```
  node 'test' do
    '<![CDATA[ <HTML></HTML> ]]>'
  end
```

RABL outputs something like:

```
<test>&lt;![CDATA[ &lt;HTML&gt;&lt;/HTML&gt; ]]&gt;</test>
```

I'd like it to output:

```
<test><![CDATA[ <HTML></HTML> ]]></test>
```

How to do that?

Comment: By writing `<![CDATA[ <HTML></HTML> ]]>`, how does RABL know you want `<HTML></HTML>` (CDATA is a special block) or plain string `<![CDATA[ <HTML></HTML> ]]>` (CDATA is part of the response)? I think you should not (and don't need to) write CDATA block on your own. RABL builds API for interchanging data in different client. The API may be not human readable, but it's fine for a program to read. Just write `<HTML></HTML>` and let RABL to escape special characters for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rabl's XML renderer uses ActiveSupport's `Hash#to_xml` internally, so you can use that function's [functionality](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/to_xml) to generate a CDATA block like this:

```
node 'test' do
  { '_' => lambda { |x| x[:builder].cdata! '<HTML></HTML>' } }
end
```

Note that I've added a "throwaway" key, since `to_xml` throws the passed key away for a proc. Take a look at the source code in the link above; there might be a better way to handle this.

Rabl renders the block above for me like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <test>
    <![CDATA[<HTML></HTML>]]>
  </test>
</hash>
```